# React Native Maps dependency issues

Tags: maven, google-maps, react-native, gradle

I'm currently trying to integrate google maps in my react native app (android side) and followed all the installation steps provided in the official docs but having some dependency issues.

Finally posting it here after trying like thousands of available solutions.

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':react-native- 
maps@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve 
com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: react-native-maps


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':react-native- 
maps@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve 
com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.2.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: react-native-maps
```

**I changed dependency resource from**

> `maven {
>       // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android 
>       binaries) is installed from npm
>               url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
>           }`

to

```
`maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }`
```

and it fixed the dependency issues for react-native-maps but got another issue

```
'error: cannot find symbol
 @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)'
```

I added both of the maven resources at the same time so that dependencies can be fetched accordingly like so

```
`allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
}
```

but again getting map dependency issues. Note that dependency issues get fixed when I add maven.google.com as the only resource for getting the dependencies.